# Android TV (Google TV) onKeyEvent in AccessibilityService is not getting called

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a very simple accessibility service, but the onKeyEvent() is not getting called, but while i am able to capture the same events in the main activity of the same application. Here is my code. I have made sure that onServiceConnected() is getting called and I am also getting onAccessibilityEvent() when operating other applications. But coudn't understand why onKeyEvent() is not getting called.

```
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
    private val myTag= "MyAccessibilityService"

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        Log.d(myTag, "onAccessibilityEvent")
    }

    override fun onKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        val actionString = when(event.action) {
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> "Key Press"
            KeyEvent.ACTION_UP -> "Key Release"
            else -> "Unknown Action"
        }

        Log.d(myTag, "Key event: ${KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(event.keyCode)}, Action: $actionString")

        return super.onKeyEvent(event)
    }


    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // Handle the interruption of the accessibility feedback
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        Log.d(myTag, "onServiceConnected")
    }

}
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeContextClicked|typeViewClicked"
    android:packageNames="com.my.myapp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true" />
```

Manifest entry:

```
        <service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibility-service"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        </service>
```

It was working fine when I was testing few days back, I don't understand what broken it, I did upgrade to latest firmware recently. But I am not sure whether it is causing it. My current android version is 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was very simple. Just need to change `android:name="android.accessibility-service"` to `android:name="android.accessibilityservice"` in the manifest file. Don't understand why android studio is suggesting to change it to `android.accessibility-service`.

[image]

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
    </service>
```